# Which Tensorflow Docker image to use?

Tags: github, docker, tensorflow, dockerhub

I just noticed that there are two Tensorflow images in existence.

There's this one:

[tensorflow/tensorflow on Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/tensorflow/tensorflow/)

and and then this one (two references):

[gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow on GitHub](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/tools/docker)

[gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow on Tesorflow.com](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux#installing_with_docker)

Is there a relevant difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The release tags, e.g., `latest`, `1.0.0-gpu`, are identical between gcr.io and Docker hub.

In other words, if you do

`nvidia-docker pull gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow:1.0.0-gpu` (from gcr.io)

and

`nvidia-docker pull tensorflow/tensorflow:1.0.0-gpu` (from Docker Hub)

you should get the same image.

However, TensorFlow pushes nightly images to only Docker Hub, see:
https://hub.docker.com/r/tensorflow/tensorflow/tags/

So if you want to use the latest nightly build, omit the `gcr.io` part, e.g.,

`docker pull tensorflow/tensorflow:nightly-py3`

Comment: Thank you. I see that the nightly has py3 appended to the end, which probably solves another question that I was wondering: getting a Tensorflow Docker image with Python 3 as the default.